# install Wndows 8 consumer preview alongside Windows 7

Tags: windows-8-preview

I downloaded the Windows 8 consumer preview 32-bit ISO, intending to install it in dual-boot config with existing Windows 7 but instead of offering the [Install on another partition option](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/dual-boot-windows-8-and-windows-7-side-by-side-1070657), it only presents a SINGLE option: **Install Now**.

How do I make it install on the free partition (that I created and formatted specifically for this purpose), **without overwriting** the current installation of Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** *Install Now* doesn't act, it only takes you to the next screens where you can configure your install.

---

> I downloaded the Windows 8 consumer preview 32-bit ISO, intending to install it in dual-boot config with existing Windows 7 but instead of offering the Install on another partition option, it only presents a SINGLE option: Install Now.

That option is when you *didn't download the ISO* and is there **to make an USB drive**, you just need to click `Install Now` instead which will launch the installer as usual. Then, continue from step 7 and select the partition.

[Here is a set of screenshots](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2012/02/installing-the-windows-8-consumer-preview-a-visual-guide.ars), note that after clicking `Install Now` and typing in the serial number you can chose whether to do a custom install or upgrade. In this case the guide has chosen for an upgrade, but if you read the text for the custom install it says that you can choose the partition.

Don't worry! The install is pretty clear and *does ask you for the details*...

---

Here is the full installation progress:

### Booting...

[image]

### What is your culture?

[image]

### Click me!

[image]

### Enter the product key to activate Windows.

[image]

### What do you want to do?!

[image]

Let's do a Custom Installation.

[image]

***Clicking Next on this screen means no going back...*** :)

Comment: Thanks! Before trying this, I just want to make sure. I *am* booting from a USB drive. :)  Are you saying that once I click `Install now`, it will just launch the installer that Paul and other tutorials mention?

Comment: @scatmoi: I've updated my answer with [a link](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2012/02/installing-the-windows-8-consumer-preview-a-visual-guide.ars). In exact order you get to the `Which type of installation do you want?` picture, then in [the other link](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-consumer-preview-dual-boot-windows-7-142631) you continue from Step 7 as you clicked `Custom Install`. I've installed both the previews from USB so I'm 100% sure... :)